# Are all known $k$-multiperfect numbers (for $k > 2$) not squarefree?

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers, divisors-multiples

I asked the following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512573) in MSE four ($4$) days ago, but so far nobody has posted an answer.

> The gist of the question is as follows:
>
> Are all known $k$-multiperfect numbers (for $k > 2$) *not* squarefree?

From my own computational verifications using WolframAlpha, it appears that a *closely related* question is:

> Are all known (*even*) $k$-multiperfect numbers (for $k > 2$)
>   *divisible* by $4$?

Thank you!

Comment: Wow!  A very quick downvote - I wonder who you are ... =)

Comment: I removed the attempted italics from the title (titles don't support that kind of formatting), and the crosspost notification from there; thank you (sincerely) for indicating this in the question. Also, the downvote seems to have been taken back.

Comment: Thank you for editing the title @ArturoMagidin, appreciate it!  =)

Comment: By the way: You may want to add a note in the math.SE post as well indicating that you have crossposted it here (perhaps as an addendum at the top or at the end)...

Comment: Aren't all the known multiperfects tabulated somewhere, so anyone can work out whether they are squarefree?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I have already tried looking for the (*most*) up-to-date lists, but J. L. Moxham's website link is broken (at least, the last time I checked), and the latest update on A. Flammenkamp's http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/mpn.html is from February 2013.  Nonetheless, I guess I'll take your cue and e-mail Achim.  Thank you!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, my profuse thanks for your reminder!  I almost forgot that one ... =)

Comment: At any rate, I will keep everyone posted on Achim Flammenkamp's response. =)

Comment: In A. Flammenkamp's [The Multiply Perfect Numbers Page](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/mpn.html), there is a MPN database facility that allows anyone to search for patterns.  Since the instructions above the database query facility section specifically state that " $\ldots$ an exponent value of 1 is omitted together with its leading ^ $\ldots$ ", and because I want to verify my initial conjecture that "All *known* (even) $k$-multiperfect numbers are divisible by $4$", I searched for the pattern "2^", copied the text extract from the website, and pasted to Notepad++. (cont'd)

Comment: My reason for using [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) is to be able to see the resulting *line count* of the text extract.  Out of the total 5307 MPNs in A. Flammenkamp's database, exactly $5305$ *are divisible by* $4$ (based from the text file's line count in Notepad++).  I will be sending an e-mail to Professor Flammenkamp to request for an "automated manual double-checking" [whatever that means =( ] of the results of my online database query, and to ask for further details regarding the *two* ($2$) exceptional MPNs.

Comment: My *best* guess is that the *two* exceptional MPNs are $1$ and $6$.  So the conjecture that all *known* (even) $k$-multiperfect numbers (for $k > 2$) are *not* squarefree is *indeed* true, which further validates Don's proof below.  My profuse thanks to everyone who contributed their ideas, particularly Don!  Much appreciated!  =)

Comment: I don't think there will be any further need to clarify / double-check with Professor Flammenkamp, but at any rate, I will send him an e-mail inquiry a bit later.

Comment: Per Professor Flammenkamp's e-mail response: "Well, from memory I know that the two smallest MPNs, namely 1 and 6 are not divisible by 4. And yes, I think all greater known MPNs have a two-power
exponent of at least 2, i.e. are not squarefree."  =)

Comment: Thank you for the downvote, I wonder who you are.  =)  (No worries, I perfectly understood.)  @wink@

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to prove that if $n$ is squarefree with largest prime factor $p \geq 5$, then $n$ is not multiply perfect. Indeed, in that case $p$ is larger than any of the primes dividing $\sigma(n)$, so that $n \nmid \sigma(n)$. So the only squarefree multiply perfect number is $n=6$ (or also $n=1$, if you allow $k=1$).

Comment: Don, I'm afraid but I don't follow your argument.  Why would $p$ be  larger than all the primes dividing $\sigma(n)$, if $p$ is the largest prime factor of a squarefree integer $n$?

Comment: Alternatively, can you cite the reference where you obtained this argument?

Comment: If $n$ is squarefree, then $\sigma(n) = \prod_{q \mid n}(q+1)$, where $q$ runs over the primes dividing $n$. Now unless $q=2$, all of the primes dividing $q+1$ are smaller than $q$. And when $q=2$, the largest prime factor of $q+1$ is $3$. So if the largest prime factor of $n$ is $p\geq 5$, then no term in the product $\prod_{q \mid n}(q+1)$ can have a prime factor as large as $p$.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, Don!  I think I get it now.